# Generate .key and .crt from PKCS12 file?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate, openssl

How exactly would I generate a .key file and a .crt file from a .p12 file?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A little googling finds [this](http://sycure.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/tips-using-openssl-to-extract-private-key-pem-file-from-pfx-personal-information-exchange/)

Hope it helps

edit: added fixed commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -nocerts -out filename.key

openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out filename.crt
```

OpenSSL can be downloaded here:

- [source](https://www.openssl.org/source/)
- [binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries)

Comment: Hmm, that wasn't the exact answer but I think I've worked it out anyway.

Comment: Perfect answer with the commands added :)

Comment: And if you want to save the key without a passphrase, add `-nodes` (no DES) before the `-out`.

Comment: openssl binary: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html